# HTML5 canvas KineticJS drawing layer

Tags: html, canvas, kineticjs

How i can drawing and save it as a layer.

```
   Add jsfiddle example, but i need could i can drawing: http://jsfiddle.net/nieszka/Z7ABH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `layer.toJSON()` to save the layer as string in the database.

Check out: http://www.zeali.net/mirrors/html5canvastutorials/kineticjs/html5-canvas-save-stage-as-json-string-with-kineticjs/index.html

To create the layer again, use `Kinetic.Node.create().`

See also: http://www.zeali.net/mirrors/html5canvastutorials/kineticjs/html5-canvas-load-stage-with-json-string-with-kineticjs/index.html

Comment: i need that I could drawing the same, not automatically